# Matlab: Access matrix elements using indices stored in other matrices

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, indexing, vectorization

I am working in **matlab**. I have five matrices `in ,out, out_temp,ind_i , ind_j,` all of identical dimensions say `n x m`. I want to implement the following loop in one line.

```
out = zeros(n,m)
out_temp = zeros(n,m)
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:m
        out(ind_i(i,j),ind_j(i,j)) = in(ind_i(i,j),ind_j(i,j));
        out_temp(ind_i(i,j),ind_j(i,j)) = some_scalar_value;              
    end
end
```

It is assured that the values in `ind_i` lies in range `1:n` and values in `ind_j` lies in range `1:m`.
I believe a way to implement line 3 would give the way to implement line 4 , but I wrote it to be clear about what I want.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks , you answer worked smoothly, though I don't know why you deleted it. Also it would be nice if you would explain how it worked.

Comment: Had to take care of a minor issue that just got resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
%// Calculate the linear indices in one go using all indices from ind_i and ind_j
%// keeping in mind that the sizes of both out and out_temp won't go beyond
%// the maximum of ind_i for the number of rows and maximum of ind_j for number
%// of columns
ind1 = sub2ind([n m],ind_i(:),ind_j(:))

%// Initialize out and out_temp
out = zeros(n,m)
out_temp = zeros(n,m)

%// Finally index into out and out_temp and assign them values 
%// using indiced values from in and the scalar value respectively.
out(ind1) = in(ind1);
out_temp(ind1) = some_scalar_value;
```

Comment: @nishantsny Sure, coming up!